# Is MediaWiki viable for sensitive information?

Tags: security, mediawiki

I was under the impression that MediaWiki is due to its nature as "open for all Wiki platform" not tailored towards managing sensitive information.

I found some warnings about this on the MediaWiki FAQ and some user account extensions as:

> If you need per-page or partial page access restrictions, you are advised to install an appropriate content management package. MediaWiki was not written to provide per-page access restrictions, and almost all hacks or patches promising to add them will likely have flaws somewhere, which could lead to exposure of confidential data. We are not responsible for anything being leaked, leading to loss of funds or one's job.

Now a consultant of my boss tells him there is no problem with sensitive information at all. I would like to hear if he is right and I worry too much.

I suppose all problems would go away if we would use separate instances of MediaWiki for every user group with the same rights.

Comment: "I worry too much."  Is it *your* job that will be lost or your boss who will be fired?  Document your concerns with your boss's boss and stop worrying.  When your boss is fired, you will be promoted, correct?

Comment: Possibly more appropriate over on Security.Stackexchange.Com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the risks here:

What sort of data are you planning on populating it with? If it is personal data such as salary, home address or medical data, or if it is credit card data then you may be required to protect it appropriately (in the US see HIPAA, Gramm-Leech-Bliley, SoX and state data protection legislation; in the UK see DPA 1988, FSA regs; in Japan JSoX; Globally PCI-DSS)

Aside from those regulations (and a whole lot of others globally) how would your business cope if the data was deleted, or published on the Internet, or modified, or corrupted?

The answers should help you define an 'appropriate' level of protection, which should then be explained along with the possible risks to the board, who should then make the decision as to whether it should go in.

(tweak the above based on company size, country etc)